# How do I add a sign to a cell without affecting formulas that use the same cell?

Tags: php, phpexcel

1. I have a cell and I need to add the sign "%" at the end of it, just for display. That cell is linked to other cells that have a formula that uses its value.
2. I have tried adding the "%" in the cell and using ABS in the formula. e.g.

   ```
   100 - ABS(H23)
   ```

   This would have worked if after I use concat in php, the output would not have added an extra single column.

   ```
    ...->setCellValue('H23', $number.'%');
   ```

   Does this to the cell

   ```
   '33%
   ```

1.. Any other solution for my title question?

2.. How do I make the output excel not have the single quote when I concatenate strings to it?

Thanks plenty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is just for display, then set the cell value correctly, and give the cell a numberFormat mask as you would in MS Excel itself.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A5', 0.33);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A5')
    ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(
        PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE
    );
```

**EDIT**

To avoid MS Excel automatically multiplying by 100 when using a percent-based format mask: using a string format mask:

```
'0 "%"'

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A5', 0.33);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A5')
    ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(
        '0 "%"'
);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's no good, the format percentage, multiplies my number by 100. I get 3300%. I need the value of the cell to be 33 and be displayed 33% ..

Comment: Ok so the percentage format, always multiples it by 100, is there any way to make my own custom format?

Comment: PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE is a simple string value, pre-defined to simplify things for developers. You can define your own strings for numberFormat masks exactly as you would in MS Excel itself using Excel's custom formats.... If you use an Excel percentage format, you also get that multiple by 100.... it's the way Excel handles any percent-based mask